# Virtualbox with Ubuntu 14.04.3 desktop not working

Tags: virtualbox

So I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 on Virtualbox, and installed the OS when I booted it for the first time. Ubuntu was successfully installed and it had me restart the machine. I did this, and logged in. At first, it seemed fine, but there was nothing for me to do (just what looked like an empty desktop that said Ubuntu in the bottom left-hand corner). After a few seconds, the Ubuntu in the corner disappeared and a menu bar appeared on the top (said File, View, etc. not part of the Virtual Machine, but the Ubuntu desktop itself). This bar only appeared for about half a second before the whole screen went black and returned me to the log in screen (the virtual machine, not my PC). I need a Linux environment to run a test driver for a code I'm working on, but this won't work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me. Please make sure that you have enabled virtuallization in your Computer's BIOS. Please reboot your machine - when it is coming up press F2 or F9 or F10 or ESC key(please refer to your computer manual for BIOS) so that you can get into the BIOS setup. Then go thru the upper level tabs/menus and find out the virtuallization setting - make it enabled. Make sure that you save the changes before exiting. Hopefully this should be the only issue.

Comment: How would I do this? Sorry, I'm not exceptionally tech savvy beyond what I need. Thank you!